# Effective way to iteratively append to a string in Python?

Tags: python, string, split, append, generator

I'm writing a Python function to split text into words, ignoring specified punctuation. Here is some working code. I'm not convinced that constructing strings out of lists (buf = [] in the code) is efficient though. Does anyone have a suggestion for a better way to do this?

```
def getwords(text, splitchars=' \t|!?.;:"'):
    """
    Generator to get words in text by splitting text along specified splitchars
    and stripping out the splitchars::

      >>> list(getwords('this is some text.'))
      ['this', 'is', 'some', 'text']
      >>> list(getwords('and/or'))
      ['and', 'or']
      >>> list(getwords('one||two'))
      ['one', 'two']
      >>> list(getwords(u'hola unicode!'))
      [u'hola', u'unicode']
    """
    splitchars = set(splitchars)
    buf = []
    for char in text:
        if char not in splitchars:
            buf.append(char)
        else:
            if buf:
                yield ''.join(buf)
                buf = []
    # All done. Yield last word.
    if buf:
        yield ''.join(buf)
```

Comment: Too bad ... So there was somebody here, who put the best answer, saying that the built-in split allowed to put more than one splitchars.
You said his code was ugly, he deleted his message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use re.split

```
re.split('[\s|!\?\.;:"]', text)
```

However if the text is very large the resulting array may be consuming too much memory. Then you may consider re.finditer:

```
import re
def getwords(text, splitchars=' \t|!?.;:"'):
  words_iter = re.finditer(
    "([%s]+)" % "".join([("^" + c) for c in splitchars]),
    text)
  for word in words_iter:
    yield word.group()

# a quick test
s = "a:b cc? def...a||"
words = [x for x in getwords(s)]
assert ["a", "b", "cc", "def", "a"] == words, words
```

Answer (score 5):

http://www.skymind.com/~ocrow/python_string/ talks about several ways of concatenating strings in Python and assesses their performance as well.

Comment: This was what I needed. Thanks. cStringIO appears the best choice for my use case.

Comment: For what it's worth: I hacked on that testcase until it ran on my Python 2.5 install, and found Method 6 (feed ''.join a list comprehension) to be consistently fastest. 6 with generator expressions turned out *slower* but still second-fastest.

Comment: In order from fastest to slowest, the methods ended up being 6, 7, 4, 1, 5, 3, 2. (7 is 6 with the brackets dropped to make it a generator expression not list comprehension). I was unable to measure memory use.

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to use re.split?

```
import re
re.split("[,; ]+", "coucou1 ,   coucou2;coucou3")
```

Comment: Didn't think of that at all. Will consider it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can split the input using [`re.split()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.split):

```
>>> splitchars=' \t|!?.;:"'
>>> re.split("[%s]" % splitchars, "one\ttwo|three?four")
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
>>>
```

EDIT: If your `splitchars` may contain special chars like `]` or `^`, you can use `re.escpae()`

```
>>> re.escape(splitchars)
'\\ \\\t\\|\\!\\?\\.\\;\\:\\"'
>>> re.split("[%s]" % re.escape(splitchars), "one\ttwo|three?four")
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
>>>
```